# expanding math expression ast

Tags: java, symbolic-math

I parsed a expression like a*(b+c) to an AST and it finally becomes: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5kTx.png,)

I'm trying to expand the expression it finally becomes a*b + a*c, but I have no idea.

I would like to found an algorithm to expand the expression, or maybe a library to do it, preferably for Java.

Comment: Essentially you would be implementing the distribution rule into your AST, noting the fact that `a*(b+c)` == `ab+ac`. So in this case, if one side of the `*` operator is addition (another `+` operation), then you can "swap" the operators such that `+` is the top level operator, and `*` is the sub-operator for both sides, with the original non-`+` operand being multiplied to the terms of the `+` operator. I don't think you'll really find a library for this, but it's not impossible to implement yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
interface AST { AST expand(); }

public class Var implements AST {
    public final String name;
    public Var(String name) { this.name = name; }
    @Override public AST expand() { return this; }
    @Override public String toString() { return name; }
}

public abstract class Binary implements AST {
    public final AST left, right;
    Binary(AST left, AST right) { this.left = left; this.right = right; }
}

public class Plus extends Binary {
    public Plus(AST left, AST right) { super(left, right); }
    @Override public AST expand() { return this; }
    @Override public String toString() { return "(%s + %s)".formatted(left, right); }
}

public class Mult extends Binary {
    public Mult(AST left, AST right) { super(left, right); }
    @Override
    public AST expand() {
        AST l = left.expand(), r = right.expand();
        if (l instanceof Plus lp && r instanceof Plus rp)
            return new Plus(
                new Plus(new Mult(lp.left, rp.left), new Mult(lp.left, rp.right)),
                new Plus(new Mult(lp.right, rp.left), new Mult(lp.right, rp.right)));
        else if (l instanceof Plus lp)
            return new Plus(new Mult(lp.left, r), new Mult(lp.right, r));
        else if (r instanceof Plus rp)
            return new Plus(new Mult(l, rp.left), new Mult(l, rp.right));
        else 
            return new Mult(l, r);
    }
    @Override public String toString() { return "(%s * %s)".formatted(left, right); }
}
```

And

```
    AST e = new Mult(new Var("a"), new Plus(new Var("b"), new Var("c")));
    System.out.println(e + " -> " + e.expand());
    AST f = new Mult(new Plus(new Var("a"), new Var("b")), new Plus(new Var("c"), new Var("d")));
    System.out.println(f + " -> " + f.expand());
```

output:

```
(a * (b + c)) -> ((a * b) + (a * c))
((a + b) * (c + d)) -> (((a * c) + (a * d)) + ((b * c) + (b * d)))
```

Comment: In addition, what is the binary implementation of subtraction and division?  thkank you.